# Max Character Limit for TextField

Tags: ios, character, textfield

I am looking to cap the amount of characters a user can type into a textfield at 14. Here is the code that I have found documentation on.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let currentCharacterCount = userNameTextField.text?.characters.count ?? 0
    if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount){
        return false
    }
    let newLength = currentCharacterCount + string.characters.count - range.length
    return newLength <= 14
}
```

but I do not feel that I am implementing this correctly. I have set

```
userNameTextField.delegate = self
```

in the viewDidLoad, and I am conforming to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.

Comment: Is it working or not? What issue are you having? The posted code's logic appears correct.

Comment: @rmaddy I am looking to cap stop the user from typing after 14 characters into the textfield. When I run this, it does not do that.

Comment: Is the code you posted called at all? If not, is the text field's `delegate` set?

Comment: @rmaddy What do you mean that my code is called? And what do you mean if the delegate is set. I have implemented delegates such as textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:). Is that what you mean? Please excuse my naiveness.

Comment: Put a breakpoint or print statement inside the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` function. Now run your app. Type into the text field. Is the breakpoint reached or does the `print` statement appear in the log?

Comment: @Kevin just put a breakpoint into this method and tell us if you get into this method. Also would be great if you describe how exactly it's not working? Does it allow to enter more than 14 chars?

Comment: It allows more than 14 chars. And I put a print statement into the shouldChangeCharactersInRange func, but after typing in more than 14 characters, it does not print anything in the console. I think this means that I am not calling the shouldChangeCharactersInRange function properly?

Comment: It means you have not set the text field's `delegate` property so none of its delegate methods will get called.

Comment: BTW - are you using Swift 3 or Swift 2?

Comment: @rmaddy Swift 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state you are using Swift 3. The signature of many methods changed in Swift 3. You need to use:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
}
```

Not the old signature posted in your question.

If it's still not being called, then you never set the text field's `delegate` property.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I needed, thank you for walking me through this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField!, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String!) -> Bool {
    let currentString: NSString = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString
    let newString = currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    return  newString.characters.count <= 14
}
```

Comment: Why? The OP's code is fine. How does this answer the question?

Comment: @rmaddy I agree that OP's code should work fine, but he states it isn't, so why not posting code without manual calculations and checks? It just feels like a less error-prone solution.

Comment: We don't even know if the delegate method is being called yet. Your answer really doesn't "fix" anything because we don't know what the exact problem is yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for swift 3:

```
let limit=4;

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = txtSMSCode.text else { return true }
    let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
    return newLength <= limit
}
```